# Pelco D Library for Arduino

Tags: programming, communication, rs485

Does anyone know of any Pelco D libraries available for Arduino?

I already have a PTZ joystick controlling 3 PTZ cameras, but I would like to add an Arduino 'intelligent' controller capable of sending automated sequences of Pelco D commands according to various PIR triggers etc.

Comment: did you succeed in using the suggested library? Ho do I determine the address of the camera to be written in the sketch?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like someone wrote a Pelco library. Check out:

https://github.com/Pixelbo/Pelco_And_Arduino